# How to redirect output to a log from expect command

Tags: linux, shell-script, scp, output, expect

I have the following code. How can I redirect the output of the expect to a log file to see if the scp has copied everything successfully. This piece of my code runs in background.

```
    export L_SRC_SID L_SID MOUNT_POINT SERVICE_PASS APP_SERVER_1 SRC_MOUNT_POINT

    #And now transfer the file over
    /usr/bin/expect -c '
    set timeout -1
    cd /$env(MOUNT_POINT)/$env(L_SID)/apps
    spawn scp -pr apps$env(L_SRC_SID)@$env(APP_SERVER_1):/$env(SRC_MOUNT_POINT)/$env(L_SRC_SID)/apps/* .
    expect {
            yes/no { send yes\r ; exp_continue }
            password: { send $env(SERVICE_PASS)\r }
    }
    expect eof
    '
```

Answer (score 3):

`expect` has an oddly named `log_file` procedure that (drumroll...) logs to files so you can usually just say

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set timeout -1
log_file blah.log
...
```

within the TCL code. See `log_file` (and also `log_user`) in the `expect(1)` man page for details.

Answer (score 2):

Simply redirect the output of your invocation of `expect`:

```
/usr/bin/expect -c '
set timeout -1
cd /$env(MOUNT_POINT)/$env(L_SID)/apps
spawn scp -pr apps$env(L_SRC_SID)@$env(APP_SERVER_1):/$env(SRC_MOUNT_POINT)/$env(L_SRC_SID)/apps/* .
expect {
        yes/no { send yes\r ; exp_continue }
        password: { send $env(SERVICE_PASS)\r }
}
expect eof
' >> /path/to/logfile 2>> /path/to/errorfile
```

Or, if you only want to capture the output of `scp`, redirect only *its* output:

```
/usr/bin/expect -c '
set timeout -1
cd /$env(MOUNT_POINT)/$env(L_SID)/apps
spawn scp -pr apps$env(L_SRC_SID)@$env(APP_SERVER_1):/$env(SRC_MOUNT_POINT)/$env(L_SRC_SID)/apps/* . >> /path/to/logfile 2>> /path/to/errorfile
expect {
        yes/no { send yes\r ; exp_continue }
        password: { send $env(SERVICE_PASS)\r }
}
expect eof
'
```